# Authenticate remote host to run ms-mpi process

Tags: ms-mpi

I want to distribute some tasks over machines over a local network.
I tried to run mpi on remote machine but it can't connect although i make sure they can talk with each other by ping.
I use MS-MPI v9 and windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the same user name and password on the remote machine.
Another way i found is making all the machines in the same domain.